# Disable Mouse Horizontal Scrolling on Linux

Tags: linux, mouse, scrolling

Recently my mouse fell on the ground and now whenever I move it, it scrolls to left or right insanely! (the problem is with the mouse, it scrolls to left/right all the time)
I'm wondering how can I disable horizontal scrolling only for my mouse and not my touchpad.
It's really annoying wherever there's a horizotal scrollbar or horizontal scrolling can be used on it!

I'm not an expert, I've searched a little but didn't found anything useful.
And I'm using debian testing.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a way to solve the problem here, but it's temporary.
You have to do it every time you plug/unplug your device, or restart or sleep/wakeup your system!

I'm giving the description in case someone else has the same problem.
First, install `xinput`.

Find your mouse id:

```
xinput list
```

Probe your mouse while charging:

```
xinput test <ID>
```

You'll probabily see button 6 (scroll to left) and 7 (scroll to right) pressed constantly.

Deactivate it:

```
xinput set-button-map <ID> 1 2 3 4 5 0 0
```

Comment: you saved my life :)

Comment: oh my God, I wanna cry. My computer was unusable until I found this. Thanks!

Comment: `xinput test 19` -> `usage: xinput test [-proximity] <device name>`